# Twocolumn: count columns instead of pages

Tags: page-numbering, two-column

I have a document in twocolumn mode. Is there a way to print column numbers in the footer instead of page numbers? Like so:

> Page 1, Column 1: **1** (left-aligned)
>  Page 1, Column 2: **2**
>   (right-aligned)
>  Page 2, Column 1: **3** (left-aligned)
>  Page 2,
>   Column 2: **4** (right-aligned)
>   etc.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[ngerman,12pt,twocolumn]{article}
\begin{document}
Column 1
\newpage
Column 2
\newpage
Column 3
\newpage
Column 4
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution

```
\documentclass[ngerman,12pt,twocolumn]{article}
\makeatletter
\def\ps@plain{\ps@empty%
 \def\@oddfoot{\reset@font\the\numexpr2*\value{page}-1\relax
 \hfil\the\numexpr2*\value{page}\relax}\let\@evenfoot\@oddfoot}
\makeatother
\pagestyle{plain}
\begin{document}
Column 1
\newpage
Column 2
\newpage
Column 3
\newpage
Column 4
\end{document}
```

**Update** For left aligned column numbers

```
\def\ps@plain{\ps@empty%
 \def\@oddfoot{\reset@font\the\numexpr2*\value{page}-1\relax
 \hfil\hspace{\columnsep}\the\numexpr2*\value{page}\relax\hfil}\let\@evenfoot\@oddfoot}
```

Comment: that looks pretty good. Can you give an alternative in case you want the right column number appear left-aligned, too (in the right column)?

Comment: @musicman answer updated