# twocolumn in latex class option, how to set page for every column

Tags: page-numbering, two-column

I want to make an A3 paper to test student. So I set the latex class option `twocolumn`. The size of each column is A4 paper. I hope each column with its own page number. When `xelatex` to PDF, I find that the PDF file's page number is A3 paper's, which located in the middle of the entire A3 paper. How can I set the page number in each A4 column. Thank you.

Comment: I think it would be easier if you used single column A4 paper and then used a tool like `pdfnup` to join pairs of pages.

Comment: ... `pdfpages`, @PhelypeOleinik?

Comment: @Bernard Better yet. I didn't think of that :)

Comment: most printing software will let you print two-pages to a sheet so you should be able to use a4 pages and simply print two-pages to A3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much, I had find a not good solution.

```
\documentclass[UTF8]{ctexart}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a3paper,twocolumn,landscape,hmargin={3.5cm,1.3cm},vmargin={1.5cm,1.5cm},footskip=0.75cm,headsep=0.25cm}

\usepackage{calc,refcount}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}
\setlength{\columnsep}{1.5cm}
\fancyfoot[CE,CO]{\kaishu{}
第~\the\numexpr2*\value{page}-1\relax~页~/~共~\the\numexpr2*\getpagerefnumber{mylastpage}\relax~页
\hspace*{.5\linewidth}
第~\the\numexpr2*\value{page}\relax~页~/~共~\the\numexpr2*\getpagerefnumber{mylastpage}\relax~页

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\blindtext
\label{mylastpage}    
\end{document}
```

ref:

- https://my.oschina.net/u/3468093/blog/2249279
- [How to use \pageref{foo} as a number?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4180/how-to-use-pagereffoo-as-a-number)
- [Twocolumn: count columns instead of pages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/266091/twocolumn-count-columns-instead-of-pages)

I cannot get the true last column. But I can set the even number.